# UISearchController: single vs separate tableview for display and search

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I need to have a search bar for a table view that displays a list of data, not sure whether I should use one table view for both displaying and searching, or have separate table views for display and search respectively.

Single table view:

+ *feels* easier to implement by just switching data source
- extra work if I want to maintain the scroll position (after searching) of the display table view

Separate table views:

+ no extra work needed to preserve scroll offset of the display table view
- extra work to switch between display and search modes

Is there anything critial I missed? What is the recommended way?

Update:

1. I need the search bar to stick on top, so it can't be the `tableHeaderView` of the table view (which scrolls when table view scrolls), or section header view because I've got different sections.

Thanks!

Comment: I would say that separating them would be the recommended way, then you have isolated views and the functionality for each separated. This should make maintenance and updates easier later on and also make your code easier to follow. When you combine them your count, cellForRow(at: and didSelectItem(at functions all need an if statement involved whereas if you separate them its much easier to read

Comment: @Scriptable Thanks, actually I'm using a view model pattern, and `cellForRow` just ask view model for a cell type without needing to know whether it's for search result or normal display, and view model only has an array of data - which can be the full list of data or filtered, depends on display/search, so this isn't a big issue. But I agree that having separate table views is tidier.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a single table view and used a read only property to filter the array of items based on the search text.

I stored the original data in Property X and based on the text entered in the search bar i filtered the data returning by the Property (readonly) Y and used as the table data source.

Using the search bar delegate method you can then filter the contents of the table as the user enters text into the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the recommended way to implement the searching functionality. Managing the datasource is easier then to handle the two different tableviews.

You can try for **UISearchController** which provides the searchBar with a TableView and can have delegate methods to handle the case.

[Here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/11/14/uisearchcontroller-add-search-uitableviews/) and [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) are some good tutorials to do the same.